# How to close a file handle opened with SHCreateStreamOnFile

Tags: c++, windows, com

Since I need to format "pretty" XML using MSXML, I am using the [trick referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164575/msxml-from-c-pretty-print-indent-newly-created-documents) to add indentation to my code. Since all I want is to save a file, I open an `IStream` using `SHCreateStreamOnFile()`. The file gets saved, I can open it in a text editor and the XML content is there. Then I call `Release()` on the `IStream` interface so that the `IStream` and the file handle get closed.

Or so I tought, however Process Explorer tell me that my process still has a reference to my file once my save function exits (despite the release). I tried calling `Release()` a second time, but still no result, the handle doesn't get closed. All Google and MSDN could tell me was that I should call `Release`... But it isn't clear if `Release()` releases only the COM object or the file handle also.

So, is there a special way to force the close of a file handle created by `SHCreateStreamOnFile()`? Or is there a better way to obtain an `IStream` on a file? Do I need to call `Release()` on the `IMXWriter`, `ISAXXMLReader` and `IStream` in a specific order?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What all are you doing with that `IStream`? You must be passing it to something that holds on to it for a while....

Comment: Check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcmfcatl/thread/8863657f-b4b2-4491-b667-26df4897e134 - related to your problem - using of smart pointers, and not releasing additional reader object

Comment: Hum, I am not using the CComPtr class, but I do however  use a custom one. I'll check that out. Also, SHCreateStreamOnFile() use an "out" parameter, instead of a return value like in the blog post you mentionned. And I did tried to Release the pointer 2 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ildjarn was right, I was passing it to an object that didn't get deleted, because I didn't knew that QueryInterface incremented the reference count ( I tought it was kind of a "COM" way of casting a pointer ). Releasing that object released the file at the same time.

A beginner mistake from someone not used to COM programming.

Comment: Use ATL for COM. CComPtr<> and CComQIPtr<> can help you avoid a lot of head aches.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those class!

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem before:

```
CComPtr<IStream> spStream;
HRESULT hr = SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(L"my.xml",
    STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE | STGM_FAILIFTHERE,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN,
    TRUE, NULL, &spStream);

SOMSXML::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDoc;
hr = pXMLDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SOMSXML::DOMDocument));
pXMLDoc->async = false;
hr = pXMLDoc->load(spStream.p);
```

You must wait execution on the destructor of **pXMLDoc** and spStream.Release(); , the handle on the file will be closed.