# Forcing MSXML to format XML output with indents and newlines

Tags: vb6, msxml

I am using MSXML 3.0 with Visual Basic 6 to store and retrieve configuration of my application. When saving the resulting `DOMDocument` to a XML file the root object gets rendered as a single very long line of text:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--WORKAPP 2011 Configuration file-->
<profile version="1.0"><frmPlan><left>300</left><top>300</top><width>24600</width><height>13575</height></frmPlan><preferences><text1/><text2/><text3/><background_color/><grid-major-step-x>50</grid-major-step-x><grid-major-step-y>50</grid-major-step-y></preferences></profile>
```

Is it possible to force MSXML to format the resulting XML file with indents and newlines?

Answer (score 8):

For such tiny files as a config the overhead of using XSL probably isn't significant anyway.  The power of SAX is more important when you're dealing with large files or tons of small ones such as the server side of a Web Service - and there you probably should not be using the heavyweight DOM in the first place.

```
Private Sub FormatDocToFile(ByVal Doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument, _
                            ByVal FileName As String)
    'Reformats the DOMDocument "Doc" into an ADODB.Stream
    'and writes it to the specified file.
    '
    'Note the UTF-8 output never gets a BOM.  If we want one we
    'have to write it here explicitly after opening the Stream.
    Dim rdrDom As MSXML2.SAXXMLReader
    Dim stmFormatted As ADODB.Stream
    Dim wtrFormatted As MSXML2.MXXMLWriter

    Set stmFormatted = New ADODB.Stream
    With stmFormatted
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        Set wtrFormatted = New MSXML2.MXXMLWriter
        With wtrFormatted
            .omitXMLDeclaration = False
            .standalone = True
            .byteOrderMark = False 'If not set (even to False) then
                                   '.encoding is ignored.
            .encoding = "utf-8"    'Even if .byteOrderMark = True
                                   'UTF-8 never gets a BOM.
            .indent = True
            .output = stmFormatted
            Set rdrDom = New MSXML2.SAXXMLReader
            With rdrDom
                Set .contentHandler = wtrFormatted
                Set .dtdHandler = wtrFormatted
                Set .errorHandler = wtrFormatted
                .putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", _
                             wtrFormatted
                .putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", _
                             wtrFormatted
                .parse Doc
            End With
        End With
        .SaveToFile FileName
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot! `.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", wtrFormatted` keeps `<![CDATA[...]]>` nodes, otherwise I got text nodes instead.

Answer (score 4):

Probably this answer will not help in your specific case, but in general it may be of use. It regards cases when the document is loaded and saved without much modification. `DomDocument` has `preserveWhitespace` property, which is initially set to `False`. If you set it to `True` before `load`, then it will be saved using the same indentation as the original file.

To add the indentation manually one may create text nodes and insert them to create new lines and spaces between elements, like this:

```
Set txt = doc.createTextNode(vbCrLf & "  ")
Call node.parentNode.insertBefore(txt, node)
```

Comment: This was actually quite useful. I do not believe that any of the proposed xslt transforms will work for versions of msxml prior to 6.0: I have spent many hours on this, and although I've yet to find a documented reason why not, I don't think the "indent" flag is supported prior to 6.0

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [this other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164575/269126) and the C++ code of the answers. But it's too much work. You're saying you're just storing a config file. So use an XSLT transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Remember to output to an [ADODB.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not to a DOM. If you output to a DOM, the XSLT serializer will be ignored.

Comment: Could you include something about where you put this into MSXML?

Comment: @MattMcNabb - You put the code in an XSLT file (like `pretty.xsl`) and then run a transformation, which can be done using the [Microsoft `msxsl.exe` command line utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) or any other XSLT processor. You could also [use the MSXML API to do the transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766561(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks; however the output isn't coming out as expected and I have [started a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133229/xslt-indent-not-working-with-msxml)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter indentation utility function that works on DOM objects and strings as input and outputs a formatted string. File handling (utf-8) is left outside its scope. Does not use ADODB streams and does not need MSXML in project references.

```
Public Function FormatXmlIndent(vDomOrString As Variant, sResult As String) As Boolean
    Dim oWriter         As Object ' MSXML2.MXXMLWriter

    On Error GoTo QH
    Set oWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    oWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = True
    oWriter.indent = True
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
        Set .contentHandler = oWriter
        '--- keep CDATA elements
        .putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", oWriter 
        .parse vDomOrString
    End With
    sResult = oWriter.output
    '--- success
    FormatXmlIndent = True
    Exit Function
QH:
End Function
```

Can be used like this

```
    sXml = ReadTextFile("doc.xml")
    FormatXmlIndent sXml, sXml
```

... so if anything fails (invalid XML, etc.) `sXml` still holds original unformatted input.