# Is there a way to modify the style sheet so that it transforms an XML document with empty tags as <tag />?

Tags: c++, css, xml, c++11, msxml

I have extracted some code from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43309/How-to-create-a-simple-XML-file-using-MSXML-in-C) to reindent an XML document.  Does anyone know how I can modify the stylesheet to make it so that the transform of an XML file will result in empty tags showing up as `<tag />` instead of `<tag></tag>`?

```
// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43309/How-to-create-a-simple-XML-file-using-MSXML-in-C
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr FormatDOMDocument(MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pDoc)
{
    LPCSTR const static szStyleSheet =
        R"!(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>)!"
        R"!(<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">)!"
        R"!(    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>)!"
        R"!(    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">)!"
        R"!(        <xsl:copy>)!"
        R"!(            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>)!"
        R"!(        </xsl:copy>)!"
        R"!(    </xsl:template>)!"
        R"!(</xsl:stylesheet>)!";

    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXmlStyleSheet;
    pXmlStyleSheet.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));
    pXmlStyleSheet->loadXML(szStyleSheet);

    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXmlFormattedDoc;
    pXmlFormattedDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));

    CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
    HRESULT hr = pXmlFormattedDoc->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void**)&pDispatch);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        _variant_t    vtOutObject;
        vtOutObject.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
        vtOutObject.pdispVal = pDispatch;
        vtOutObject.pdispVal->AddRef();

        hr = pDoc->transformNodeToObject(pXmlStyleSheet, vtOutObject);
    }

    //By default it is writing the encoding = UTF-16. Let us change the encoding to UTF-8

    // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pXMLFirstChild = pXmlFormattedDoc->GetfirstChild();
    // A map of the a attributes (vesrsion, encoding) values (1.0, UTF-8) pair
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNamedNodeMapPtr pXMLAttributeMap =  pXMLFirstChild->Getattributes();
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pXMLEncodNode = pXMLAttributeMap->getNamedItem(_T("encoding"));
    pXMLEncodNode->PutnodeValue(_T("UTF-8"));    //encoding = UTF-8

    return pXmlFormattedDoc;
}
```

Comment: If anyone knows how or why this code works, please leave a comment, because it's beyond me. Especially the bit where we get the vtOutObject and somehow it ends up in a completely different formatted document pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet causes empty tags to be written where possible (with MSXML6):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(normalize-space()) and not(comment()) and not(processing-instruction())]">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is achieved by avoiding the `xsl:copy` for elements with no child elements, text, comments or processing-instructions, and "manually" copying the element using `xsl:element`. Note that the attributes are copied too with the nested `xsl:copy-of`.

For example, this XML document:

```
<Document>
<empty> </empty>
<empty-2/>
<non-empty>
Some text
</non-empty>

<non-empty-2 some-attribute="attribute text">
<empty-3/>
<non-empty-3><empty-4/><empty-with-attribute another-attribute="some more text">    


</empty-with-attribute>
</non-empty-3>
</non-empty-2>

<abc:non-empty-with-namespace xmlns:abc="urn:test:abc">
<abc:empty-with-namespace abc:namespaced-attribute="namespaced attribute text"/>
</abc:non-empty-with-namespace>

<non-empty-comment>
<!-- A comment -->
</non-empty-comment>

<non-empty-proc-instr>
<?some-instruction?>
</non-empty-proc-instr>

</Document>
```

would be transformed into the following using your `FormatDOMDocument` function, with the updated stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <empty/>
    <empty-2/>
    <non-empty>
Some text
</non-empty>
    <non-empty-2 some-attribute="attribute text">
        <empty-3/>
        <non-empty-3>
            <empty-4/>
            <empty-with-attribute another-attribute="some more text"/>
        </non-empty-3>
    </non-empty-2>
    <abc:non-empty-with-namespace xmlns:abc="urn:test:abc">
        <abc:empty-with-namespace abc:namespaced-attribute="namespaced attribute text"/>
    </abc:non-empty-with-namespace>
    <non-empty-comment>
        <!-- A comment -->
    </non-empty-comment>
    <non-empty-proc-instr>
        <?some-instruction?>
    </non-empty-proc-instr>
</Document>
```

To restrict empty tags to only certain elements by name, you can adjust the `match` pattern to add a check on the element name: `contains('|list|of|element|names|',  concat('|',name(),'|'))`. Note that that list of names is separated with a `|`, and there's a `|` at the start and end of the list too, and we concatenate the element name with those delimiters as well. This trick enables us use `contains` (which just matches any substring) to achieve the effect of searching in the list.

For example, allowing empty tags for the `non-empty`, `empty-2`, `empty-4` and `abc:empty-with-namespace` elements in my previous example, the updated stylesheet would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains('|non-empty|empty-2|empty-4|abc:empty-with-namespace|',  concat('|',name(),'|')) and not(*) and not(normalize-space()) and not(comment()) and not(processing-instruction())]">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output of `FormatDOMDocument` would become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <empty></empty>
    <empty-2/>
    <non-empty>
Some text
</non-empty>
    <non-empty-2 some-attribute="attribute text">
        <empty-3></empty-3>
        <non-empty-3>
            <empty-4/>
            <empty-with-attribute another-attribute="some more text"></empty-with-attribute>
        </non-empty-3>
    </non-empty-2>
    <abc:non-empty-with-namespace xmlns:abc="urn:test:abc">
        <abc:empty-with-namespace abc:namespaced-attribute="namespaced attribute text"/>
    </abc:non-empty-with-namespace>
    <non-empty-comment>
        <!-- A comment -->
    </non-empty-comment>
    <non-empty-proc-instr>
        <?some-instruction?>
    </non-empty-proc-instr>
</Document>
```

Note that though we specified `non-empty` as a possible empty tag in that list, that it doesn't come out as empty, because it actually has a text node (which is what we want). Also, note that `empty` wasn't in our list, and it comes out with a closing tag as `<empty></empty>` which was what we wanted in this case too (similarly for `empty-3`).

Comment: Wow.  I totally don't understand this. :D  But it works.  I need to sit down and take a closer look at how this stuff works later.

Comment: Hmmmm, not sure why, but I can't seem to give you another 50.  I try adding a bounty to this question and it'll only give me 100 as an option.  Can a moderator please tell me why this is so?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can the indent characters be changed from tabs to *n* spaces?

Comment: I don't know whether this can be done with MSXML's XSL indenter. Some other XSL processors have their own extension attributes on `xsl:output` in a custom namespace for specifying the indentation, for example `xalan:indent-amount` or `saxon:indent-spaces`.

Comment: Re bounty, http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty says "... if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).". But don't worry about awarding another bounty I already got +50 :-)

Comment: Hrm.  Well sorry about that. :(  I don't understand why such a restriction is even necessary.

Comment: @Adrian The main reason is because +50 bounty might often result in more than 10 upvotes due to the attention, so people started to abuse it just to harvest reputation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yeah, I got that now.  But then there should be a way of transferring directly, circumventing that issue.

Comment: @Adrian there are already feature requests for this, [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23841/transfer-award-reputation-between-users) the most relevant - I highly doubt it will be done, but it's also not declined yet.

Comment: Not exactly for the same reason, but the outcome is the same.  Thanks @ShadowWizard.