# Insert newline before XML root node to get formatted output

Tags: c++, xml, dom, msxml

I create XML documents by creating a full-blown in-memory DOM model and storing it to a file by using the IXMLDocument::save method. To format these documents, I use the trick with creating a text node consisting entirely of newline and tabs. This trick works well inside a node, but at the document level it fails. As a result, I get partially aligned documents like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--Main Comment--><Root>
    <InputFile>
        <FileName>Part1</FileName>
        <FileDirectory>D:\Document Folder\Testing</FileDirectory>
    </InputFile>
    . . . . .
</Root>
```

Is there any other trick to insert a newline before the main comment and before the root node? I prefer a solution that is limited to C++ DOM interfaces and does not involve external tools or libraries.

Comment: If you can use XSLT transformation, it is trivial. And you won't need to use newline and tab tricks.

Comment: (1) https://www.codeguru.com/database/doing-xslt-with-msxml-in-c/ (2) https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169497&seqNum=2

Comment: (3) https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/MSXML/Xslt/cpp/XSLT.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Here is XSLT based solution.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

The `indent="yes"` attribute will indent the entire XML.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your solution would be good if it worked. First, it has the same problem as my original version: there are no line breaks before the main comment and before the root node. Second, even though it inserts line breaks before each subnode, it doesn't insert tabs and so there is no indentation.

Perhaps, all this can be eliminated with a small fix in the .xslt file; I would appreciate it if you do.

Comment: Please connect with me on LinkedIn

Comment: I did a more thorough search and found a number of exactly the same complaints: When using MSXML, formatting with XSLT does put each subnode on separate line, but without indentation. So, this is a common problem and I'm not going to fight it now. Pretty formatting is nice to have, but my original solution is also acceptable to our users. But thank you anyway: knowing about XSLT transformations can be useful in other situations.

Comment: Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164575/msxml-from-c-pretty-print-indent-newly-created-documents